# How to understand the ip header definition of 4.4BSD?

Tags: c, bsd

```
struct ip {
#if BYTE_ORDER == LITTLE_ENDIAN
    u_char  ip_hl:4,
            ip_v:4;
#endif
#if BYTE_ORDER == BIG_ENDIAN
    u_char  ip_v:4,
            ip_hl:4;
#endif
  ......
};
```

Why does it change the offset in a byte for `ip_hl` and `ip_v`? I think the big endian and little endian is used to describe the displacement of a byte in a word.

Comment: It looks like they're making what are normally unwarranted assumptions about how compilers behave (but it may be correct for BSD). As you say, byte order normally is the sequence of bytes in a multibyte data type, but this is within a bit-field. There needn't be a correlation between the two orders. The compiler must document how the bit-fields are laid out. BSD could work as shown — in fact, it must. On SPARC or other big-endian platforms, the bit order for fields in the storage unit of a set of bit-fields must be different from the bit order on little-endian platforms such as Intel machines.

Answer (score 0):

To be pedantic about the terminology it is important to realize that the offset of the bitfields is not really changed -- rather the *order* of the bitfields is changed.  If there were three equal-sized bitfields you would not see any difference in the offset of the middle one and the fact that the intent was to reverse the order of their allocation would be more obvious.

And yes, "endian" typically describes the order of bytes in a word, but for all 4.4BSD systems the order of allocation of bitfields also follows the order of bytes in a word for that system's CPU architecture.

(I think that may actually be true for all UNIX System V ABIs too -- it has been in all of those I'm aware of.  There are non-unix systems though which do not follow this rule of thumb!)